# Llenar dataset de Delphi desde arreglo de Java

Tags: java, webservice, delphi-2010

Tengo una inquietud: se puede llenar un Dataset en Delphi desde un array generado por Java, sin necesidad de hacer ciclos (for, while)?

Por ejemplo: Un método GET me devuelve como respuesta:

> (([], 'N', True, nil, False, 17, 22386, True, 'INTERESES SERVICIOS
>   PUBLICOS', True, 22387, False, False, $37A3398, True, $37A3410, True,
>   '0', True, 2.79, True, 'D', True, 'D', True, 'ACUMULA', True,
>   'INTERES', True, 0, True), ([], 'S', True, $93C9900, True, 1, 12422,
>   True, 'CUOTA DE ADMINISTRACION', True, 12422, False, True, $37A3488,
>   True, $37A3500, True, '0', True, 0, True, 'D', True, 'D', True,
>   'UNICA', True, 'CUOTA', True, 0, True)).

Es un arreglo con dos posiciones, y cada posición me trae los datos de un objeto. Normalmente debo hacer un FOR para llenar cada campo del dataset. Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de llenarlo sin hacer ciclos para que sea más rápido.

Comment: Me parece que Java no tiene nada que ver con esta pregunta. Lo que consumes desde Delphi es un servicio web, independiente de si el servicio fue creado con Java, .Net, Python, etc. Tu pregunta debería estar más enfocada sobre cómo leer el contenido de la respuesta de tu petición GET (XML, JSON, Yaml, lo que fuese) en Delphi y se almacene directamente en un `DataSet`

Comment: Tienes razón, Luiggi. Gracias por la aclaración.